# Running a PowerShell script inside a Batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I've been trying to integrate a PowerShell script inside a Batch file but I seem to get some errors when trying to do so.

This is my code so far:

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%A in (C:\MACs.log) do (

@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe "& arp -a | select-string "%%A" |% {$_.ToString().Trim().Split(" ")[0]} >> C:\tempfile.log
```

Ok so, when I run this command in PowerShell everything is working OK but in Batch I get some token errors.

The main post of this code is to create a loop from the MACs.log where I have a couple of MAC addresses that I want the IP addresses to and output them to tempfile.log.

If someone can lend a helping hand it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? Just run the PowerShell script directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly solve it from the batch file?

```dos
(for /f %%a in ('
    arp -a ^| findstr /l /i /g:"c:\MACs.log" 
') do @echo %%a) > c:\tempfile.log
```

The inner pipe command will execute the `arp` and filter its output using the mac addresses found in `MACs.log`. This list is processed by the `for /f` command that will retrieve the first token in the line (default behaviour), that is, the ip address, and echo it. All the output is sent to a tempfile.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The Powershell string seemed easier initially. I'm gonna use the code you suggested. Thx a lot! Cannot upvote your post as I don't have enough Rep... +1 :D